# How to erase/delete entire Elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: elastic-beanstalk

I ran `eb init` and set stuff up only to realize that RDS is *essentially* required if you use a relational database, but you'll only be prompted for it if you pass `--database` option to the `EB create` command (definite oversight there IMO).

Anyway, `eb terminate` only seems to terminate the ec2 instance, not erase the environment information. So, if you want to start fresh with the same environment... you would have to do `my-app-<env>2,3,4,5,6`? That seems like garbage.

How do you COMPLETELY erase the environment information with the CLI tool?

Answer (score 7):

I believe that `eb terminate --all` will accomplish what you're looking for.

That being said, I'd recommend *against* creating an RDS database that's associated with your EB instance. If you do so, then the instance and database are tightly coupled, meaning that if you decide to terminate the instance, the associated RDS database will be destroyed. Among other drawbacks, this will prevent you from implementing blue/green deployments.

In my opinion, it's more flexible to do the following:

1. Create the EB instance without an RDS instance
2. Create the RDS instance
3. Set the appropriate environment variables on the EB instance to associate the two instances together

In Rails at least, the environment variables you'll need to set are as follows:

- RDS_HOSTNAME=yourinstance.region.rds.amazonaws.com
- RDS_DB_NAME=ebdb
- RDS_PASSWORD=password
- RDS_USERNAME=adminuser
- RDS_PORT=5432

Comment: Thanks Brian. I've moved on, but if I hit this situation again, I'll give it a try.

Comment: This will leave a temporary ghost environment in your settings these a supposed to be cleanup by automation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `eb delete` to delete the environment. You can make use of MySQL and Postgres externally to RDS perfectly fine.

Comment: Tried that already, but danke. `eb: error: unrecognized arguments: delete` EB CLI 3.8.4 (Python 2.7.1)

Comment: EB CLI 3 no longer has the delete command. It is not present in the docs and there doesn't seem to be a replacement:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cmd-commands.html